# Custom permalinks structure for custom posts

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a SEO problem as the structure of the site on WordPress is squad.

The site has ordinary cutters and are custom. They are structurally interested in information, but not in the URL. The task of tie them. The solution has never been found on the Internet.

Example:

Page
https://website.com/page1
https://website.com/page2

Custom Post Type
https://website.com/custom/page1/post1
https://website.com/custom/page2/post2

I need cut /custom/ and put this post1 under page1 of that page and another posts under another pages.

In register_post_type I was made rewrite
`

```
'rewrite'             => [
                    'slug' => '/',
                    'with_front' => false
                    ],
```

`
so this remove my /custom/. Can any say me where I can find guide how to transfer this custom_post_type under /page*/?

I tried change permalinks via permalinks plugin, but it doesn't solve my issue.